# Removing zero images from a tensor in TensorFlow efficiently

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I have a set of `50` images of shape `(50,128,128,1)` which is represented as a tensor in TensorFlow. Let's say that the `25th` and `30th` image are just zero images but I do not know which images are all zero beforehand (`25th` and `30th` in this example are just to make the case clearer). I wish to remove such images and have a tensor which is of size `(48,128,128,1)`. How can this be achieved in Tensorflow without looping through the `0th` dimension of the tensor `50` times and checking for each image if `tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(image_i))>0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Dataset.map(some_fn)`. Here you can define `some_fn` that will check each tensor's value with your logic `tf.reduce_sum()`. SO, if the value of `total` is zero then you can neglect it otherwise you can keep it.

```
def some_fn():
    image = tf.fill([8,8], 0)# dummy tensor values
    image_row = tf.slice(image, [1,0], [1, -1])
    total = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(image_row)) # total = 0
    return total
```

You can read [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=stable#map) more. This is not a loop, it works in parallel on each element (each image in your case.) So it is fast.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please post a sample working example with an arbitrary tensor of size (50,x,y,1) so I can try it out quickly and understand the code executing it?

Comment: Thank you again. But your edited answer doesn't use `Dataset.map`. I guess you gave the answer for the logic to use in `some_fn`. If you could edit it please, I can accept the answer

Comment: I have made some edits. Sorry for it not being clear earlier. None the less, I hope it has helped you. Also, please accept the answer. Cheers!